# How to set a field value based on a long list of other fields

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm looking for a best practice suggestion here as there are a couple of ways to solve this.

Based on if any of about 40 fields have *any* value I want to run a specific approval step.

So my first guess out of the gate was to create a new custom field and then use a formula to set the value. But since the 40 fields have a variety of types (picklist, text, checkbox) that was proving rather tedious (and I guess I would hit some sort of limit rather quick).

So my second guess was a trigger. So as I was coding I thought it would make sense to create a new object that contains the list of fields and then just reference that in my trigger. Cleans up the code a bit and makes maintenance a bit easier.

I'm a bit new to the platform, so I might have missed something obvious that others know about.

Any ideas that I might have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_SObject_instance_methods.htm) has map-like methods that work well for this type of logic. There are also compile-time checked `SObjectType` tokens that can be used as the keys (instead of name strings). So where you want to execute the same logic on many fields you can just iterate over the fields:

```
trigger MyTrigger on MyObject__c (...) {
    SObjectField[] fields = new SObjectField[] {
        MyObject__c.Field1__c,
        MyObject__c.Field2__c,
        ...
    };
    for (MyObject__c o : Trigger.new) {
        for (SObjectField f : fields) {
            if (o.get(f) != null) {
                ...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the specifics of what your particular problem, note that you'll need to take care to code such a trigger to check for changing values and to check that there isn't already an active approval process.

Comment: Yeah that looks good. I guess keeping the list of fields in the trigger itself is as good as keeping it in an external table/object.

thanks for the information!

Comment: @LeeFranke If you want to change the set of fields then a custom object (or probably better a custom setting) might make sense. Or if the set of fields is fixed but needs to be used in several pieces of code then they could be shared via a class. Note that you will see a lot of in-line code examples for triggers and that is an appropriate way to start. But like any code, as the complexity grows common code should be factored out into separate classes and frameworks introduced if they add value.

Comment: More than likely won't be used in any other places as this is fairly specific. The list of fields will probably change but probably just once a year or so (we make most of our changes at the fiscal year). So just keeping the list in the trigger as in the example will probably work well in this circumstance.